Swift not using initialiser when creating a view
I have a specific SwiftUI View that I am using to add and edit variables. When I add the variable, I call the view using this:
Button(action: {
    showingDeviceManager.toggle()
}, label: {
    Text("Add Device")
}) .sheet(isPresented: $showingDeviceManager, content:{
        DeviceEditorView(onScreen: $showingDeviceManager)
    })

And the device editor has this initialiser:
init(){
    editMode = false
}

However, to edit the devices, I need to pass in my data type, so I made this new initialiser:
init(editDevice: Device){
    editMode = true
    self.device = editDevice
}

And call it like this:
Button(action: {
    showingDeviceManager.toggle()
}, label: {
    Text("Edit Device")
}).sheet(isPresented: $showingDeviceManager, content:{
        DeviceEditorView(onScreen: $showingDeviceManager, editDevice:device)
     })

However, when I show the value of editMode, it still shows false.
Both of the buttons are outside of the view that is being called.
EDIT: Cut down on extraneous code

Please show a [mcve].

@Sweeper I cut down on the code, is it better now?

Note, you should not launch a sheet within the Button label, move this outside the Button and use .sheet(item: ...).

@workingdogsupportUkraine the sheet within a Button label was a mistake that I made when transferring the code over, my bad. Can .sheet(item:) be used to open up a view?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Bits of disconnected code is not enough. Yes, .sheet(item: ...) is how you should pass your device thing to the sheet view. You can also capture the variable, using .sheet(...) { [device] in ...}

@workingdogsupportUkraine is there any clean way to do  .sheet(item: ...) ? The issue I'm having with that is that my data type has many variables, and would make the code very long.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.

The signature of the init you have added and the init you are calling don't match. You need init(onscreen: Binding<Bool>, editDevice: Device){}

@Echo31416 did my answer help ?

You don’t normally need custom inits for View structs.
In this situation it’s best to use sheet(item:) where item is the data type you want to edit.

The issue is that the data type has a lot of variables that need to be initialised, and placing with item: would make my code very messy. Additionally, I have a lot of category variables that I would need to set, and Pickers didn't seem to work when I tried them out.

item is usually a struct that contains all of the variables you need, make it an optional state, set it when you want the sheet to appear.

I believe you're not using the init you wrote. If the device property is Binding, you should write you want a Binding value in your custom init:
init(editDevice: Binding<Device>){
    editMode = true
    self._device = editDevice
}

